# Why is Array.concat method defined twice in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I noticed that the `Array.concat` method in TypeScript is defined twice in the language's official type definition file. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b970fa4ae510c0e108670e497df967a05645a6a7/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1326-L1337) is the method's definition:

```js
/**
 * Combines two or more arrays.
 * This method returns a new array without modifying any existing arrays.
 * @param items Additional arrays and/or items to add to the end of the array.
 */
concat(...items: ConcatArray<T>[]): T[];

/**
 * Combines two or more arrays.
 * This method returns a new array without modifying any existing arrays.
 * @param items Additional arrays and/or items to add to the end of the array.
 */
concat(...items: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]): T[];
```

I am curious as to why it is defined twice and if there is any difference between the two definitions. Could someone please explain the reason behind this duplication and clarify the distinction, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this and it looks like a leftover from a historical problem that isn't directly relevant today.  At one point (TypeScript 2.0-ish) TypeScript's declaration for [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) had [a single call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c578367c26bdb24ccb2320e2cab5ca5459edfe39/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1115) to account for both single elements and arrays inside the input (since [this behaves differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#concatenating_values_to_an_array)):

```
interface Array<T> {
  concat(...items: (T | T[])[]): T[];
}
```

But this had an issue when the inner element was a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), resulting in a bug report at [microsoft/TypeScript#9901](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9901), where

```
var a : Array<[number, number]>= [[1, 2]];
a.concat([[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]); // error!
```

would fail because the compiler saw `[3, 4]`, and `[5, 6]` as type `number[]`, while `[7, 8]` was the expected `[number, number]`.  The `T | T[]` was confusing the compiler in the face of tuples. They decided the fix would be to add an overload (actually "re-add" an overload, feel free to research the full crazy history yourself in GitHub) that first tries to see the input as a single array type before trying to account for mixed arrays.  This was done in [microsoft/TypeScript#9997](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9997), resulting in [this pair of signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e8bd372bb2b9815a589b16759323d089390d2be0/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1115-L1120):

```
interface Array<T> {
  concat(...items: T[][]): T[];
  concat(...items: (T | T[])[]): T[];
}
```

That fixed the problem.

---

Since then there have been a number of changes:

- [microsoft/TypeScript#17806](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17806) changed the use of `T[]` to `ReadonlyArray<T>`.
- [microsoft/TypeScript#20455](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20455) changed that to `T[] | ReadonlyArray<T>`.
- [microsoft/TypeScript#21462](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21462) changed that to a new `ConcatArray<T>` which is a supertype of `T[] | Readonlyarray<T>`.

which leads to the current signatures:

```
interface Array<T> {
  concat(...items: ConcatArray<T>[]): T[];
  concat(...items: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]): T[];
}
```

So that's the "reason", from a historical perspective.  Conceptually you should only need the second call signature, but the first one was added to work around a bug.

---

The thing is, that bug doesn't seem to exist anymore even if you remove the first call signature:

```
interface MyArray<T> {
    // concat(...items: ConcatArray<T>[]): T[];
    concat(...items: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]): T[];
}

declare const a: MyArray<[number, number]>;
const r = a.concat([[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]); // okay
// const r: [number, number][]
```

I presume some tuple handling changed significantly since TypeScript 2.0.  So at this point, there might not be any reason for the first call signature to exist.  An interested party might want to raise a GitHub issue asking for its removal.  Such an issue might or might not be well received; destabilizing `concat()` might be more trouble than it's worth.  But this is out of scope for the question as asked, so I'll end there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CCUp3QHgBUA+ZAbwChlrkB6W5BAexATjAAoA6H4SAWwDOALmQBhFmzDZcBEgG0AugEpRhJQG4qNZq3bdeAkcg6FkAH3GT2MvEWLKlq5OsVaAvhQoATCAgA2cFAouoJgyHCiGLYE8iAArvwARtAANMgJydCKxFqh4VDIALwRXLpSHPLyAMzpACyK6fIArOkAbI3I8gDs6QAciipa9IwsYchQonGJKVDpmbOKSkA)

Comment: This answer is very detailed, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The Array.concat method is not defined twice in TypeScript; it has a single definition. It's part of the standard JavaScript Array prototype and is accessible in TypeScript as well.

If there's a perception of duplication, it might be due to the fact that TypeScript provides type annotations for JavaScript methods, and these annotations are part of the TypeScript standard library declarations. However, the actual implementation of Array.concat is part of the JavaScript runtime, and TypeScript inherits and augments these types.

To use Array.concat in TypeScript, you might see type annotations like this:

```
concat<T>(...items: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]): T[];
```